# Running client side languages on a Surface 2 (HTML, CSS, JS)

Tags: html, web, client, surface, windows-rt

I have a Windows Surface 2 tablet. I want to display a website I developed on this device. It is running only client side languages so I wouldn't need anything like an apache server running. Can I render a local html file on my device and view it like it was hosted.

Comment: What HTML?  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you write your question in a way that will help us help you.

Comment: @jbrown It would be a local html file on the Surface device.